# Migrating Homepage from Django to React

Tags: reactjs, django

i built a Homepage using the `Django templating engine` and on one page is a js application i wrote. Now i moved to a Frontend <-> Backend architecture with `React` and `Django-rest-framework`.

The Application i had in Django was served as a `.html` file with `<script>` tags for the js part.
Now i moved to React and i'm serving the html elements through a React component and through React-helmet i'm adding the `<script>` tags for this specific page. The actual `.js` files reside in the `/public` folder of react.

I thought i can replicate this way the old structure. But now i get Errors that the `.js` files can't import `classes` from the first external script.

What could be the difference in this setup ?

Django:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://unpkg.com/quantum-circuit"></script>
<script defer src="{% static 'path/to/file.js' %}"></script>
...
```

React:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://unpkg.com/quantum-circuit"></script>
<script defer src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +  'path/to/file.js' }></script>
...
```

The Error Message at React is that my `file.js` can't find the import from the first `<script>`. But in Django there is no problem.

[image]

the import statement in `file.js` is:

```
import { QuantumCircuit } from "quantum-circuit";
```

Thank you in advance for every answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the first external script is not ready when my custom scripts are trying to call it.
I fixed the issue using the `useEffect` hook. It calls the external script and if it's ready i'm calling my custom scripts.

Despite i was able to resolve this issue, i'm wondering why this hasn't happend in Django before.